# scanf a string in a char pointer

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I want to scan a string and point a `char` pointer to this scanned string.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *string;
    scanf("%s",&string);
    printf("%s\n",string);

}
```

But gives a warning saying

> warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2
>   has type 'char **'

How do I scan a string in a `char *` without warnings.

**Edit** : It worked for the below code with warnings and I drilled down it to the above one so to be very specific.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int n = 2;

    char *strings[2];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%s",&strings[i]);
        printf("%s\n",&strings[i]);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Allocate memory for string variable first then pass only `string` instead `&string`.

Comment: In other words, you're asking how to make the compiler error go away when you haven't figured out how to allocate a memory buffer yet.

Comment: ... or use a fixed-length string. It depends on what you're planning on reading.

Comment: When you say "this works", does that mean you actually tested it? Because I don't see how it does anything but crash.

Comment: @interjay You're most likely correct, but then, It's UB.....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, `%s` in `scanf()` expects a *pointer to `char`*, not a *pointer to pointer to `char`*.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2 / p12, `fscanf()` (*emphasis mine*)

> `s`
>  Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters.<sup>286)</sup>
>   If no `l` length modifier is present, the corresponding argument shall be a
>   **pointer to the initial element of a character array** large enough to accept the
>   sequence and a terminating null character, which will be added automatically. [...]

Change

```
scanf("%s",&string);
```

to

```
scanf("%s",string);
```

That said, you need to allocate memory to `string` before you actually try to *scan* into it. Otherwise, you'll end up using uninitialized pointer which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: how to allocate memory beforehand?