# Unable to store string input into a char pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, scanf

I've just started learning how to code in C for uni. I'm trying to take a step up from char arrays and trying to store strings in char pointers, but for some reason the terminal is giving me a weird error.

I'm using CLion and the Ubuntu Terminal. When I run the command `make main`, it creates a `make` in the directory, but returns a warning:

```
main.c:6:19: warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument 
[-Wformat=]
scanf("%[^\n]%s", s);
             ~^
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s;
    scanf("%[^\n]%s", s);
    printf("Hello World! %s\n", s);
}
```

And then when I run `./main`, the program outputs: `Hello World! (null)`. I'm literally passing a char* into scanf so I don't really know what is causing this error. As a matter of fact, when I tried replacing `%s` with `%*c`, `make` tells me that `*c` expects an `int`! I'm honestly pretty confused about his whole thing, so any help would be quite appreciated.

Comment: @user3121023, that makes sense! So is there a way to fix this code, or would I have to change the pointer to an array?

Comment: Try to remove the 2nd percent sign.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921081/scanf-a-string-in-a-char-pointer)

Comment: Does `scanf("%[^\n]", AllocatedBuffer);` work?

Comment: `char s[100]; if (scanf ("%99[^\n]", s) == 1) printf ("Hello World! %s\n", s);`

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/37549594/694576 if not a duplicate to it.