# Problem with " 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[1]'"

Tags: c, warnings

```
FILE *fd;
char File_name[]="";
<...>
printf("Enter the name of the file where you want the results to be saved. \n");
    printf("DON'T FORGET that file must end with .exe \n");
    scanf("%s",&File_name);
    while(strchr(File_name,'.txt')==NULL)
    {
        printf("The end of the file name is not correct. Please try again. \n");
        printf("File name: ");
        scanf("%s",&File_name);
    }
```

Warning:
format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[1]' [-Wformat]
scanf("%s",&File_name);
~~~~^~~~~~~~~~

Arrow goes to "&File_name".

How to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Aside: `char File_name[]="";` is not big enough to input *anything*. it is an array of length `1` which can hold only the nul string terminator.

Comment: The compiler is saying that `scanf("%s",&File_name);` should be `scanf("%s",File_name);` An array passed to a function decays to a pointer, so you don't need the indirection.

Comment: But I have empty char, and user write file name and somehow program should put that saved file name into char. Or maybe you have other ideas?

Comment: 1. Compiler says "boohoo this line is bad: `scanf("%s",&File_name);` Specifically, the bug is here `<arrow pointing at the bug>`" . 2. Stare intently at that line. Could it actually be bad like the compiler says? 3. You don't actually need to understand what the compiler error means to find yet another `&` goof-up bug. There's an arrow pointing out the bug for you, how much more obvious can it get?

Comment: `&File_name` => `File_name`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf a string in a char pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921081/scanf-a-string-in-a-char-pointer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` expects `char*` for `%s`.

`File_name` has type `char[1]` because it is one-element array and the element is initialized to `'\0'`.

Most arrays in expressions are converted to a pointer, but one of the exception is an operand of unary `&` (this case).

Therefore, `&File_name` becomes a pointer to the array and its type is `char(*)[1]`.

To fix, remove the `&`s before `File_name`. Then the array `File_name` will be converted to `char*` pointing at its first element.

Also:

- 1 element is definitely too short to read strings. Allocate more elements by specifying number of elements like `char File_name[512] = "";`.
- `'.txt'` is a multi-character character constant. Its value is implementation-defined and will not be what you want. You should use `strstr(File_name,".txt")` instead of `strchr(File_name,'.txt')`. (`strstr` is for searching for strings (including middle), not for checking suffix, but it will behave better than `strchr()`).